# What are the units of the total_votes in the producer_info structure?

Tags: block-producer, javascript, voting

The structure is defined here

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/7bce267c6e48bcbf2d81f0ed51a3771501fdbb7b/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.abi#L134

total_votres is a float64

The value reported by eosjs is 8176413791976091025408.00000000000000000 for the bohdanjungle producer, but the UI for that testnet gives the total votes as 1013 EOS (http://dev.cryptolions.io/#).

If I add my vote of 100 EOS to bohdanjungle would it's vote total increase to 8176413791976091025508.00000000000000000 ?